# An small image stretches in ImageView with the larger dimensions than the main image

Tags: xamarin.android, imageview

I have an image (116*109 pixels).

I have an imageview (150dp * 150dp).

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp" />
```

```
            ImageView iv = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView3);
            iv.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.house1);
```

Main image stretches in ImageView, why?

I do not use `android:scaleType="fitXY"` and `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the src will not stretch the image while set the background will:

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"     
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:contentDescription=""
        android:src="@drawable/ttt"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" 
    />
```

Or in code behind:

```
    ImageView iv = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView3);
    iv.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ttt);
    iv.SetScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CenterInside);
```

Refer: [ImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView#attr_android:scaleType)